# API for changing user roles in Google Groups for Business

Tags: java, python

Using the provisioning API, I have been able to create groups and add users to them. I have serached high and low for an API that will allow you to assign roles to users for example to make them managers or owners.

This can be done manually, but I havent found a way to automate this process. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

How about: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/reference#Group_Members_Table

More info here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#assigning_an_owner_to_a_group

Please try a Google search in the future before posting on SO.